# Android - How to access already created database from other class?

Tags: java, android, android-sqlite, sqliteopenhelper

Here is my **SQLiteOpenHelper** class :

```
public class MySQLiteHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

...
//all the code


SQLiteDatabase db;

String url;
String title;
String init_price;
String cur_price;
byte[] image;

// Database Version
private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;
// Database Name
private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "ProductsDB";

// Products table name
private static final String TABLE_NAME = "products";

// Products Table Columns names
private static final String KEY_ID = "id";
private static final String KEY_URL = "url";
private static final String KEY_TITLE = "title";
private static final String KEY_INIT_PRICE = "init_price";
private static final String KEY_CUR_PRICE = "cur_price";
private static final String KEY_IMAGE = "image";
private static final String[] COLUMNS = {KEY_ID, KEY_URL, KEY_TITLE, KEY_INIT_PRICE,KEY_CUR_PRICE, KEY_IMAGE};

//An array of database
String[][] table = new String[10][5];
byte[][] images = new byte[10][1];

int len = 0; //no.of rows in the table

public MySQLiteHelper(Context context) {
    super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
}

@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {

    this.db = db;

    // SQL statement to create a products table
    String CREATE_PRODUCTS_TABLE = "CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_NAME + " ( " +
            "id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, " +
            "url TEXT, " +
            "title TEXT, " +
            "init_price TEXT," +
            "cur_price TEXT," +
            "image BLOB" +
            " );";

    // create products table
    db.execSQL(CREATE_PRODUCTS_TABLE);
}

@Override
public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
    // Drop older table if existed
    db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + TABLE_NAME);

    // Create tables again
    onCreate(db);
}


void read() {

    int i = 0;

    // 1. build the query
    String query = "SELECT  * FROM " + TABLE_NAME;

    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();

    Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(query, null);

    if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
        do {

            table[i][0] = cursor.getString(0);
            table[i][1] = cursor.getString(1);
            table[i][2] = cursor.getString(2);
            table[i][3] = cursor.getString(3);
            table[i][4] = cursor.getString(4);
            images[i] = cursor.getBlob(5);
            i++;
        } while (cursor.moveToNext());
    }
}

String[][] getTable() {
        return table;
    }

    }
```

My **List** class :

Here in this class, I want to create a listview from the values in the database.

**How do I access those values?**

**List.java :**

```
public class List extends Activity {

 MySQLiteHelper obj = new MySQLiteHelper(this);

    // I have all the methods to get required data from database.
   // But I'm unable to call those methods directly. Why?
  // I actually can access those methods from a service. 
 // But now, I'm getting "Cannot resolve method" error.



 MySQLiteHelper obj = new MySQLiteHelper(this);

 obj.getLength(); //I'm getting error here
 obj.read(); // It says that it cannot resolve the method.

        }
```

Why is that? I put the same code in a thread inside List.java class and then I'm able to access those methods.

Comment: are those methods public?

Comment: Yeah! Some are with NoModifer, some with public. But I cannot access any.

Comment: Check your import statements

Comment: They are under same package.

Comment: Can you post more info,  as it is right now in your question, you have one empty and one almost-empty class, so its really hard to tell what is exactly going wrong. Thx.

Comment: Okay! I'll update the question with details.

Comment: @petey Please look at my updated question. Thnx.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. MySQLiteHelper  has no method for `getLength()` but that is ok. (more on this at the end)
2. the `read()` method is not public, and it really does nothing other than populate the table member/field of the `MySQLiteHelper` class.
3. You aren't leveraging the `getTable()` method you created (which also is not public).

lets go ahead and make `getTable` public (consider renaming this as it is really returning table data and not an actual database table, up to you tho), and anytime it is called,  lets also call read() anytime this method is called

```
// renamed from getTable
public String[][] getTableData() {
    read();
    return table;
}
```

With this small modification, your usage should look something like this:

```
 MySQLiteHelper obj = new MySQLiteHelper(this);
 String[][] tabledata = obj.getTableData();
 // get the Length  (no getLength() method needed as we will poll the tabledata length property.
 int length = tabledata.length;
```

I'm going to assume (and I apologize if I'm incorrect) that this your first crack at doing android databases.  So it might be good to read a tutorial like this one:

http://www.androidhive.info/2011/11/android-sqlite-database-tutorial/

HTHS :)

Comment: Thanks @petey. It's working! :) Yes, it is my first try at Android. Will follow your suggestions, thanks a lot for your time. :)

Comment: Awesome! just work the CRUD methods for your table and I think you will have your app in shape very soon!